# How to move TFS 2010 repository

Tags: tfs

Is it possible to specify the repository drive?

I.E. Can I set in TFS 2010 that the repository is on a fileserver or another drive and How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Tfs repository is stored in a SQL Server Database then the solution is to move the database to another location (server).